# Display and update a TimeSpan

Tags: c#, wpf

...Hello,

I explain the problem : In my XAML code, I binded an element with the propertie "Duration" of my class "mTask".
"Duration" type is TimeSpan.

When I start a method from the class "mTask" called mStart, I want to update the propertie "Duration" during the execution of the method, and display it thanks to the binding.

But the problem is I don't know how to keep updated the time span. I was thinking about create a DateTime at the beginning of the method and substract it to the current DateTime.Now during all the execution, is it the solution?

If you need more information, just ask!

Thanks,

Y.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to write the start time to a field and to let the property "Duration" return DateTime.Now - _startTime.

Update:
The class mTask must implement INotifyPropertyChanged and Raise the event of this interface, whenever the value of the property changes. In your case, the value of the property is calculated on the fly, so you would need to raise the event cyclically while your method mStart runs.

Comment: Hum, not working for the moment, but I think there are lot of other problems. I'll check when I will have solve them ;)
Thanks

Comment: To update the binding, you need to Raise the PropertyChanged event, every time you want the UI to be updated.

Comment: I have already done : UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged is it what you're speaking about ?

Comment: No, that was not what I meant, because that's the default. What I meant was: The class mTask must implement INotifyPropertyChanged and Raise the event of this interface, whenever the value of the property changes. In your case, the value of the property is calculated on the fly, so you would need to raise the event cyclically while your method mStart runs.

Comment: Ouch, Ok, most difficult than I was thinking !
I am gonna try this, it should work, thanks ;)

Comment: Lol it raised a StackOverflowException... :p
I check again, don't worry I'll vote up ;)

Comment: Yes it is. Don't know why, but ther eis an endless loop on the private set of my propertie!

Comment: I understood the problem : this is th ecode of my propertie :

            get
            { 
                return (Etat);
            }
            private set
            {
                Etat = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Etat");
            }

The private set was endlessly calling it self, so I removed the line Etat = value;
Then, the get is endlessly calling it self... So I wanted to remove the code to write :

            get;
            private set
            {
                OnPropertyChanged("Etat");
            }

But the compiler doesn't accept it, and I duno why

Comment: You need a backing field for your property.

Comment: Yes, I did it and it worked !
I didn't know it was an obligation to use a backing field!
Whatever, thanks for the help! :)

Y.

Comment: It is only necessary, if you want to do more than just retrieving and storing the value, like raising an event.